# Invalid MIME types

Tags: 14.04, mime-type

So each time I try to install a new package, I get an error saying:

```
Error in file "/usr/share/applications/AESCrypt.desktop": "all/allfiles" is an invalid MIME type ("all" is an unregistered media type)
```

I don't really understand what this means, and I have no idea on why it's happening... It only started recently when I removed TeamViewer 9 using dpkg, and installed TeamViewer10 using dpkg.

Comment: Do you have AESCrypt installed?  If yes, do you need it?

Comment: I need it to encrypt personal data.

Comment: [Edit] your question ans post the contents of the `AESCrypt.desktop` file. (I know how desktop files work, but do not have AESCrypt, so we'll see where this gets us) ;-)